# About i++ Executing Order in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Lets see this

```
i=0;
s = 'aaa-'+(i++);
s+= 'bbb-'+(i++);
s+= 'ccc-'+(i++);
s+= 'ddd-'+(i++);
s+= 'eee-'+(i++);
s+= 'fff-'+(i++);
document.write(s);
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/ynSmW/

I expecting get:

```
aaa--1
bbb-0
...
```

but I got

```
aaa-0
bbb-1
...
```

Why? Should it be (i++) execute first, so output is `i+1`?

Comment: Why do you expect `-1`? You're setting `i` to zero and only ever incrementing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i++ first retrieve i and then increments it

Comment: Use ++i for the expected result

Comment: Why bracket does nothing?

Comment: The brackets say only that this operator must be executed first in the chain of instructions but the behaviour of the operator still remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

`i++` is executed after your statement.
use `++i` for the contrary.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B.2B_.28Increment.29) is the explanation. In short, value of *i* is passed before increasing.